# How to read a text file and store words to a Vector in scala?

Tags: scala, vector

New to Scala and Vector
How to read a file word by word and store in a vector in scala?
For example I have a file.txt as below

test1
test2
test3

I want to load it to a vector v1 which looks like Vector(test1,test2,test3)

Comment: @SethTisue, why don't you put it as an answer so people can really upvote and accept that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming one word per line:

```
io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines.toVector
```

a good place to look this kind of thing up is scalacookbook.com, so e.g. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples

Comment: scala> val all2 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/dev/app/extractList.txt").getLines.toVector  
all2: Vector[String] = Vector(ABC, DEF, Line3, Line4)    it worked